# Server Side (PHP) filtering and ordering with Ajax and infinite scroll

Tags: php, ajax, filtering, jquery-isotope, infinite-scroll

I have implemented the infinite-ajax-scroll plugin onto my project (https://github.com/webcreate/infinite-ajax-scroll) .  Its a PHP project which displays a long list of divs. The infinate scroll uses server side pagination. I also have server side filtering and ordering and ideally would like this to use Ajax so that it works nicely with my infinite scroll.  How do I pass the filters using Ajax?  I have found tutorials on how to filter using JQuery but none none of this using PHP.

I did find http://isotope.metafizzy.co/ which has both filtering and infinite scrolling capabilities but in the documentation it advises against using both together which is a massive shame for me as it looks like a great plugin.

Can anyone advise on my best approach to this?  If I need to reset the infinite scroll when new filters are selected then thats fine.  But how would I do this and how do I pass the selected filters to the infinite scroll?

Below is what I have thus far.

```
    $cat = (isset($_GET['cat']) ? urldecode($_GET['cat']) : ''); 
    $page = (int) (!isset($_GET['p'])) ? 1 : $_GET['p'];
    $start = ($page * $pagelimit) - $pagelimit;
    $limit = $pagelimit*$page; 

    //get total number of discounts for search
    $total_items = Stuff::countItems($cat);

    if( $total_items > ($page * $limit) ){
      $next = ++$page;
    }

    //get items
$items = Stuff::getItems($cat, $sortby, $dir, $start, $limit);

if(!$items){
  header('HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found');
  echo 'Page not found!';
  exit();
} 

?>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ias.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
          $(document).ready(function() {
            // Infinite Ajax Scroll configuration
            jQuery.ias({
              container : '.wrap', // main container where data goes to append
              item: '.item', // single items
              pagination: '.paginate', // page navigation
              next: '.paginate a', // next page selector
              loader: '<img src="css/ajax-loader.gif"/>', // loading gif
              noneleft: 'No more items', //Contains the message to be displayed when there are no more pages left to load
              triggerPageThreshold: 5, // show "load more" if scroll more than this to stop
              trigger: "Load more items"
            });
          });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="wrap">    
        <?php
        echo 'TOTAL: '.$total_items .'<br />';

        //filter through categories*/
        echo 'FILTER BY CATEGORY:';
        foreach ($categories as $category){
            $categoryURL = urlencode($category);
            echo "<a href=\"index.php?cat=$categoryURL\">$category<a/> | ";
        }       
        //loop through and display items
       foreach ($items as $id => $item){

           echo "<div style=\"border:1px solid green;margin-bottom:5px;\" class=\"item\" id=\"item-$id\">
                    ID: $id <br />
                    $item[name]<br />                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
                    $item[cat]<br />
                    $item[description]<br />
            </div>";
        }
        ?>
    <!--paginagation-->
    <?php if (isset($next)): ?>
    <div class="paginate">
      <a href='index.php?cat=<?php echo $cat?>&p=<?php echo $next?>'>Next</a>
    </div>
    <?php endif?>
    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: So you want to specify a filter with html/javascript and submit it via AJAX to your server side script, did I get that right? If so, what kind of filter?

Comment: I'm also trying to figure out what part of this isn't working for you. The category should be filtering - what isn't happening that should be?

Comment: Yes the category is filtering but only after re-loading the page.  I'm trying to load the new results using ajax when the filters are applied.  I would then probably need to reset the infinite scroll.  Then on I would need to pass the selected filters (category) so that the infinite scroll works with the selected filters.  Hope that clarifies it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Infinite scroll and filtering makes sense only if you apply the filters on both client (for already loaded data) and server (for future pages to be loaded).

But after applying some totally different filter or sorting I would think that a user would like to be brought back to the first page (or scrolled back to top for infinite scroll).
Losing some already loaded results is the only way. You could maybe [cache](https://github.com/paulirish/jquery-ajax-localstorage-cache) those results to improve speed a bit.

To make this easy I recommend you start using [KnockoutJS](http://knockoutjs.com/) or some similar client-side MVC library. jQuery is good for so much complexity. At some point you find out you need something better.

[Here's a cleaned up extract](http://jsbin.com/OBOveME/2) of an app I worked on some time ago that needed something similar. ([edit link](http://jsbin.com/OBOveME/2/edit))

You won't need that "page" parameter at all. I used it so that my "fake" provider could return sequential, readable, names.

Server-side you need to know at any moment (so maybe `$_SESSION`) for the current query how many results you've sent to the client.

Something like this:

```
function getResults($query) {
    if($_SESSION['query']['category'] !== $query['category']) {
        if(!array_key_exists($query['category'], $_SESSION['resultsSent'])) {
            $_SESSION['resultsSent'][$query['category']] = 0;
        }
        $_SESSION['query'] = $query; 
    }

    $sql = 'SELECT * FROM foo WHERE category = ? LIMIT ?, ?';
    $data = $db->select($sql, array($_SESSION['query']['category'],  $_SESSION['resultsSent'][$query['category']], 10);

     $_SESSION['resultsSent'][$query['category']] += count($data);

    return json_encode($data);
}

if(!array_key_exists('query', $_SESSION)) {
    $_SESSION['resultsSent'] = array();
    $_SESSION['query'] = array(); // maybe some defaults here?
}

if(array_key_exists('query', $_POST)) {
    echo getResults($_POST['query']);
}
```

You'll have to write a `resultsService` that does the AJAX call.
Probably something like this:

```
function resultsService() {
    this.query = function(query, success) {
        jQuery.post({
            url: 'index.php', 
            data: query,
            success: success
        });
    }
}
```

After that all you have to do is slap your infinite scroll library on top.

This relies on the fact that (1) on the client you never remove data already loaded, you just hide it if it does not fit the current filters and (2) for each possible filter combination your server knows how much data it sent so that it does not send it back again.

If you have more complex filters with results that are not exclusive (one result may be returned for multiple filter combinations - think *price*, *rating* and *number of rooms*, not *categories*) then you'll eventually end up sending duplicates to the client. There's no real solution to this other than resetting your whole list. You could try and keep track of all the individual results you've sent to the client, not only the count, and filter them out while querying (`WHERE id NOT IN (1, 2, 17, 20, ...)`) but this will definitely not work for large amounts of data.

For sorting there absolutely is no solution other than knowing exactly what you've sent to the client or, obviously, resetting the list.

I'm `POST`ing a JS object as a `JSON` encoded string (ko.toJS(this.query)) and then `json_decode`ing it in PHP. 
No matter how you build that JS object, sending it as `JSON` is better than manually serializing it yourself as `GET` parameters.

Also it's best if you use a common format for all your filter types and handle them by a set pattern server-side.

For `['category': 1, 'subcategory':2, 'user': 1234]` I'd define `categoryFilter`, `subcategoryFilter` and `userFilter`, call them using `call_user_func` and pass the filtered value as a parameter along your query, adding bits to it for each one.

```
$query = DB::table('stuff');

$filters = json_decode($_POST['query']);
foreach($filters as $filterName => $value) {
    $query = call_user_func_array($filterName . 'Filter', array($query, $value));
}

$results = $query->get();

function categoryFilter($query, $value) {
    $query->where('category_id', '=', $value);

    return $query;
}
```

How your actual code will look like and how easy you'll be able to build the SQL query depends on what you are using. The DB class I've used above is the one bundled with [Laravel](http://laravel.com/docs/queries#selects).

On the client-side building the query object should not be that hard even with basic jQuery.

Comment: Thanks for the in depth response. I have done a lot of work on this and don't want to start changing everything to start using Knockout, but thanks for the suggestion, I will look into this in the future. I would be happy just to reset the list when new filters selected.  I am not great with Ajax and so was just looking for advice on how to apply filters using ajax and pass these filters to the infinite scroll

Comment: See my edited answer above for an idea about applying filters server-side.

Comment: thanks for that, but how do I pass the selected filters through to infinite scroll?

Comment: Both of those infinite scroll libraries expect a selector for the "next page" URL as a configuration parameter. You therefore won't be able to `POST` anything to it. Either JSON serialize the filters and send them as a `GET` parameter or dig into those libraries' documentation and find out how you can supply your own "load" function. Paul Irish's version (https://github.com/paulirish/infinite-scroll) accepts a custom "load" callback function parameter and should be pretty straight-forward to implement.

Answer (score 0):

Think about this way: when you do filtering, you change the whole result so you need reload data and reset the scroll. That's why you shouldn't using both filtering and infinite scrolling together.

I did the same thing in my previous project. Hope it works for you.

Comment: yeah I'd be happy resetting the scroll.  I think I'd expect that.  How did you do it in your previous project?  Can you advise on what to use for Ajax filtering that would reset the scroll?

Comment: I used [Facescroll](http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex11/facescroll/index.htm). By default it doesn't support infinite scrolling but the scrollbar can be dynamically added to a piece of content so we customize the library to handle infinite scrolling.
<br/>
Our filtering is an instant searching. When user type a character, we setTimeout to call an ajax function.
`$('#searchInput').keydown(function(event) {
 if (windowDrawing.searchTimer) {
  clearTimeout(windowDrawing.searchTimer);
 }
 windowDrawing.searchTimer = setTimeout(function() {
  myWindowProcess.ajaxGetWindows();
 }, 200);
});`